# Gravitational redshift and special relativity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, redshift

> Consider a redshift experiment in the Earth’s gravitational field and
> assume that a special relativistic theory of gravity exists, which
> need not be further specified here. For such an experiment we may
> neglect all masses other than that of the Earth and regard the Earth
> as being at rest relative to some inertial system. In a spacetime
> diagram (height $z$ above the Earth’s surface versus time), the Earth’s
> surface, the emitter and the absorber all move along world lines of
> constant z. he transmitter is supposed to emit at a fixed frequency
> from $S_1$ to $S_2$. The photons registered by the absorber move along world
> lines $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$, that are not necessarily straight lines at an angle
> of 45◦, due to a possible interaction with the gravitational field,
> but must be parallel, since we are dealing with a static situation.
> Thus, if the flat Minkowski geometry holds and the time measurement is
> given by (2.5), it follows that the time difference between $S_1$ and $S_2$
> must be equal to the time difference between $A_1$ and $A_2$. **Thus, there
> would be no redshift**. This shows that at the very least (2.5) is no
> longer valid. The argument does not exclude the possibility that the
> metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ might be proportional to $\eta_{\mu \nu}$.

**How do they conclude that? Why the fact that the proper times are the same imply that there is no redshift?**

[image: experiment]
[image: proper time]

SOURCE : (Graduate texts in physics) Norbert Straumann -General relativity-Springer (2013)

Answer (score 2):

Emitter says: I emitted $N$ wave crests during time $t$.

Absorber says: I absorbed $N'$ wave crests during time $t'$.

We know that $N'= N$ and the text says that $t'= t$

Well, for me that above looks like the defintion of "no redshift". Absorber received what emitter emitted, no change, no shift of any kind.